# Python: use main function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have code with many functions and main, when I am trying to run the code it's not working and showing like it run successfully. When I am run the debugger it's show me that it run only on the functions' names. so I am pretty sure the problem it's with the main. how can i solve it?

Comment: Share the logs or code.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to ask a new question. Instead, simply ask a new question; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.

Answer (score 3):

`main()` is not run implicitly (like in C or Java). In Python you have to explicitly call if you want your code to run.

```
def main():
    some_code()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()  # actually run main
```

Note that `main` does not have to be named `main` - it may be arbitrary named function. Moreover, code to run does not even have to be enclosed in any function. Consider file with content like that:

```
print "abc"
```

It'll simply print "abc" on standard output.